# Lucene : searching without stop words does not return results

Tags: lucene

I'm using Lucene.net 3.0.3 and I don't understand how stop words are supposed to work in queries.

I have this text as input : `Stop the word`

I used a StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30) for index and querying. The index has one field `Title`

The field is set to be stored and analyzed. I played with different TermVector, too.
For query parsing I use the simple QueryParser.Parse and

This is the issue :

- Query for `Title:stop the word` returns the doc - this is good
- Query for `Title:stop word` does not returns the doc - I was expecting it since stop words are removed from index.

Then I switched to LUCENE_24 and the second query actually returns the document.

I understood that stop-words are removed from the index, and probably from query, but it seems that I'm missing something basic.

Comment: stop words wouldn't be removed from query, but they would be ignored for the actual searching/results.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, but TopDocs.TotalHits returns 0 docs.

Comment: are you sure that all 3 of your input words didn't get declared stopwords and ignored? Not sure how lucene goes about it, but most other search engines that do this sort of thing will consider words that occur more than 50% of the time to be stop word candidates.

Comment: I'm using the standard English stop word list and it does not have "stop" and "word" in it. I used Luke.net to inspect the index and it shows stop and word as terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the word is indeed removed during analysis, the default behavior after 2.9, it appears, is to have position increments enabled.  So, while the word is removed and will not contribute to scores, in phrase queries it is expected that "stop" and "word" will have a (removed) term between them.  In Lucene 2.4, this functionality existed, but was turned off by default.  You can see this in the implementation of `StopFilter.getEnablePositionIncrementsVersionDefault`:

```
public static boolean getEnablePositionIncrementsVersionDefault(Version matchVersion) {
    return matchVersion.onOrAfter(Version.LUCENE_29);
}
```

If you were to try, for instance, searching for "stop into word", I expect you would see a hit with version 3.0.

The [PositionIncrementAttribute documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/PositionIncrementAttribute.html) briefly gives the idea:

> Set it to values greater than one to inhibit exact phrase matches. If, for example, one does not want phrases to match across removed stop words, then one could build a stop word filter that removes stop words and also sets the increment to the number of stop words removed before each non-stop word. Then exact phrase queries will only match when the terms occur with no intervening stop words.

Comment: Yes, this is what I observed as well. I would think that probably I can just remove the stop words from data at index time, and then from the query when it is interrogated.

Comment: But I was thinking more from a search perspective : do you think that it takes sense that the default behavior (at least in lucene.net 3.0.3) is to not return the match if I have a stop word between them ? I don't see the reason why this would be the default behavior.

Comment: I see the rationale behind it, if that's what you're asking.  The word "stop", in particular, is used in a much different way between the two cases, so the presence of a removed word provides information on usage of the word.  The removal of stop words isn't really meant to create fuzzy matching (there are plenty of ways to do that), it's meant to enhance performance and improve scoring by not evaluating a bunch of meaningless matches.  Maintaining those benefits while keeping as much information as possible definitely makes sense to me.

Comment: Probably I should give a better example as input : Lucene is awesome. There is no match for "lucene awesome" using the standard query parser. It sounds like I need to change the query is built, or have a custom analyzer for stop words.

Comment: Consider this:  "their" is a default stop word.  "our" is not.  If you want "get stuff" to match "get our stuff" you would need to set the slop to 1 or higher in the phrase query.  Should the behavior be different for "get their stuff"?